# linux command . Copy a file one hundred times

Tags: linux, shell

I need the right syntax to copy file.jpg 100 times with one command so to get
100 files named file001.jpg, file002.jpg, ..., file100.jpg.
I'm using this but not working for me 
any tips

```
#!/bin/bash

for x in `seq 1 100`; do

    if [[ x -lt 10 ]]; then cp file.jpg file-00$x.jpg;

    elif [[ x -lt 100 ]]; then cp file.jpg file-0$x.jpg;

    else cp file.jpg file-$x.jpg;

    fi

done
```

Comment: You could use `$(printf "file-%03d.jpg" $x)` to get the filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your two `if` conditions, you're missing the `$` on `$x`, so you're ending up comparing the string `x`, rather than the number.

As Basile Starynkevitch notes, though, the `printf` utility is probably a much better way to go here: `$(printf "file-%03d.jpg" $x)` gets you the right formatted string in a single line.

Comment: If you use arithmetic comparision, you can omit the `$` -- `if (( x < 10 )); then ...`

Answer (score 20):

Using bash [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion)

```
for n in {001..100}; do
    cp file.jpg file-$n.jpg
done
```